# How to put event for column using react-bootstrap-table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-bootstrap-table

I am working with table in my react application, I am using [React bootstrap table2](https://react-bootstrap-table.github.io/react-bootstrap-table2/) for this, I am successfully rendering the table.

**Please do check the edited part**

- I am facing issue in rendering the table data conditionally
- I have one column named as `Availability` so it is true and false, what I am trying to do is when it is true show tick mark (right) if false show cross one, I am able to insert new column but I am not able to update the existing one.

**What I was doing to insert new column**

```
let c = {
  dataField: "Class",
  text: "Class",
  editable: false,
  formatter: () => {
    return 12;
  },
};
d.push(c);
setColumnData(d);
```

Above `d` is columnData

But I am stuck here to update the existing one

**My  data**

```
{
  column_data: [
    {
      dataField: "first_name",
      text: "Name",
      sort: true,
    },
    {
      dataField: "last_name",
      text: "Last Name",
      sort: false,
    },
    {
      dataField: "availability",
      text: "Available",
      sort: true,
    },
  ],
  tableData: [
    {
      first_name: "simon",
      last_name: "chaz",
      availability: true,
    },
    {
      first_name: "steve",
      last_name: "smith",
      availability: false,
    },
    {
      first_name: "michel",
      last_name: "gread",
      availability: true,
    },
    {
      first_name: "rimon",
      last_name: "class",
      availability: false,
    },
  ],
}
```

This is how I am rendering table:

```
<BootstrapTable
  bootstrap4
  keyField="certificate_Name"
  data={data.tableData}
  columns={data.column_data}
  wrapperClasses="table-responsive"
  classes="table-hover table-bordered"
  headerClasses="header-class"
/>;
```

- If `Availability` is true then I want to show `<i className="ri-checkbox-circle-line"></i>`.
- if `Availability` is false then `<i class="ri-close-line"></i>`

**I am trying to show my cell data on specific condition**

[Here is my code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-shadow-vke5u?file=/src/App.js)

**Edit**

I have updated my code sandbox withe the above solution,

If it is true I am showing whatever I want to else What else I want to.

```
{
    dataField: "available",
    text: "Available",
    sort: true,
    formatter: columnFormatter  // this I am putting 
  }
```

And here is my function

```
 const columnFormatter = (cell, row, rowIndex, formatExtraData) => {
  if (row && row.availability) {
    return <a href="#">check this out</a>;
  } else {
    return row.availability;
  }
};
```

now in if condition I am trying to put an `event` `onClick` but I am not able to achieve that.

[I was going through this link](https://react-bootstrap-table.github.io/react-bootstrap-table2/docs/basic-row.html) but this is for on each row click, I want to click on specific column to specific cell.

[updated code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-shadow-vke5u?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? adding an `onClick` handler to your `<a>` element works just fine

Comment: i tried but it is not working, could you show mw one working code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding an `onClick` handler is as simple as:

```
<a
    href="#"
    onClick={() => {
      console.log("clicked row", rowIndex);
    }}>
    check this out
</a>
```

[image: Edit pensive-driscoll-eobpe]

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to conditionally render the icons based on availability
based on this

- If Availability is true then I want to show  `<i className="ri-checkbox-circle-line"></i>`.
- if Availability is false then `<i class="ri-close-line"></i>`

so try doing this

```
const columnFormatter = (cell, row, rowIndex, formatExtraData) => {
  if (row && row.availability) {
    return <svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-check-circle-fill" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M16 8A8 8 0 1 1 0 8a8 8 0 0 1 16 0zm-3.97-3.03a.75.75 0 0 0-1.08.022L7.477 9.417 5.384 7.323a.75.75 0 0 0-1.06 1.06L6.97 11.03a.75.75 0 0 0 1.079-.02l3.992-4.99a.75.75 0 0 0-.01-1.05z"/>
</svg>
  } else {
    return <svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-x-circle-fill" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M16 8A8 8 0 1 1 0 8a8 8 0 0 1 16 0zM5.354 4.646a.5.5 0 1 0-.708.708L7.293 8l-2.647 2.646a.5.5 0 0 0 .708.708L8 8.707l2.646 2.647a.5.5 0 0 0 .708-.708L8.707 8l2.647-2.646a.5.5 0 0 0-.708-.708L8 7.293 5.354 4.646z"/>
</svg>
  }
};
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-bird-e389g?file=/src/App.js:228-1118